# Comparison retrieving same value as differences

Tags: oracle

I am trying to compare the date fields between two of my tables **T1** and **T2**.

I have framed a query similar to below and doing the comparison:

***Query***:

```
SELECT distinct t1.id t1_id, t2.id t2_id, t1.source t1_source, t2.source t2_source, to_date(t1.t1_date,'MM-DD-YYYY') t1_date, to_char(t2.t2_date,'DD-MON-YY')  t2_date
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
AND t1.source = t2.source
and to_date(t1.t1_date,'MM-DD-YYYY') <> to_char(t2.t2_date,'DD-MON-YY');
```

Though the `T1_DATE` and `T2_DATE` are one and the same, the results are popping up that they are not equal.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
T1_ID    |  T2_ID    |  T2_SOURCE | T2_SOURCE | T1_DATE   | T2_DATE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
123      |  123      |  SOU       | SOU      |  17-FEB-47 | 17-FEB-47
234      |  234      |  SOU       | SOU      |  01-JAN-49 | 01-JAN-49
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- I did copy pasted `T1_DATE` and `T2_DATE` to notepad and confirmed that they don't have any leading or trailing spaces.
- I verified from the table that they don't have any leading or trailing spaces.
- The date condition I added for comparison too doesn't have any spaces.

I now updated my query to add `trim` to my condition:

***Updated query***:

```
SELECT distinct t1.id t1_id, t2.id t2_id, t1.source t1_source, t2.source t2_source, to_date(t1.t1_date,'MM-DD-YYYY') t1_date, to_char(t2.t2_date,'DD-MON-YY')  t2_date
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
AND t1.source = t2.source
and trim(to_date(t1.t1_date,'MM-DD-YYYY')) <> trim(to_char(t2.t2_date,'DD-MON-YY'));
```

And now it worked fine. What is happening in the backend?

Please advice.

Comment: what are the datatypes of t1.t1_date and t2.t2_date?

Comment: varchar2 in T1 and date in T2

Comment: does t2 have a time part? do you want to compare only the date part?

Comment: T2 has only date part. Comparing only date part is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

When you compare with:

```
to_date(t1.t1_date,'MM-DD-YYYY') <> to_char(t2.t2_date,'DD-MON-YY');
```

you are comparing a date on the left-hand side with a string on the right-hand side. That is forcing Oracle to do an implicit conversion so that they are both the same data type, to allow the values to be compared.

The [data comparison rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-98BE3A78-6E33-4181-B5CB-D96FD9DC1694) say:

> - When comparing a character value with a DATE value, Oracle converts the character data to DATE.

So the string you just generated is converted back to a date, so you're really doing:

```
to_date(t1.t1_date,'MM-DD-YYYY') <> to_date(to_char(t2.t2_date,'DD-MON-YY'))
```

... which used your NLS settings, and your NLS_DATE_FORMAT appears to be DD-MON-YY too. The string is going to be '17-FEB-47', and when you convert that back to a date with the two-digit YY format mask that [uses the current century](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-6C75461E-2E18-4C35-9EB4-038A7E1C9C1F), so it comes out as 2047, not 1947. So you end up effectively doing:

```
date '1947-02-17' <> date '2047-02-17'
```

... which is true, as the dates are in different centuries, hence your rows are displayed.

But when you do:

```
trim(to_date(t1.t1_date,'MM-DD-YYYY')) <> trim(to_char(t2.t2_date,'DD-MON-YY'))
```

you are now comparing two strings. The left-hand side is converted to a date  and now that is implicitly converted back to a string, again using your NLS setting, and the right-hand side isn't modified. So you end up effectively doing:

```
'17-FEB-47' <> '17-FEB-47'
```

... which is false, so the rows are not shown.

---

So, either leave the right-hand side as its original date value:

```
to_date(t1.t1_date,'MM-DD-YYYY') <> t2.t2_date
```

or if that has a time part you want to ignore then truncate it, but leave it as a date:

```
to_date(t1.t1_date,'MM-DD-YYYY') <> trunc(t2.t2_date)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TZvAfGVQ)